# Why JavaScript selection sort hangs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have the following code:

```
var longLorem = "..."; // here is a string, > 1 000 000 length
var bufferSize = 1000000;
var lorem = longLorem.substring(0, bufferSize - 1).split('');
var swap; 
var i, j;
for(i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<bufferSize;j++){
    if(lorem[i] > lorem[j]){
        swap = lorem[i];
        lorem[i] = lorem[j];
        lorem[j] = swap;
    }
    }
}
```

Why it hangs under Chrome? How to speed up JavaScript or it is not possible as it is for DOM and UI, etc.?

With `bufferSize=100 000` it completes in 2m 35s.

The following C program completes in >17m

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define bufferSize 1000000

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int i,j;
   char swap;
   FILE *loremFile = fopen("lorem.txt", "r");

   char buff[bufferSize];
   fgets(buff, bufferSize, (FILE*)loremFile);
   fclose(loremFile);

   //printf("'%s'\n-----END--------\n", buff );
   for(i=0; i<bufferSize-1;i++)
   {
       for(j=i+1;j<bufferSize-1;j++)
       {
           if((int)buff[i] > (int) buff[j])
        {
            swap = (char)buff[i];
            //printf("%c with %c\n", buff[i], buff[j]);
            buff[i] =(char) buff[j];
            buff[j] = swap;
        }
       }
   }
   //buff[bufferSize-1] = '\0';
//   for(i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
//     printf("%c", buff[i]);
//   }

   printf("'%s'\n-----END--------\n", buff);
   printf("exit\n");

   return 0;
}
```

And C# code completes about 10m:

```
using System;

namespace MySort {
    public class Some {
    public static void Main() {
        int bufferSize = 1000000;
        string loremFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("lorem.txt");
        var chars = loremFile.ToCharArray(0, bufferSize);

        for(int i = 0; i<bufferSize; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<bufferSize; j++) {
            if(chars[i] > chars[j]) {
            char swap = chars[i];
            chars[i] = chars[j];
            chars[j] = swap;
            }
        }
        }

        Console.Write("'");
        Console.Write(chars);
        Console.Write("'\n");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the most important question for us at the moment is "why?" - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @6502 That's just cruelty lol

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I just was curious about speed of technologies

Comment: What's the point of comparing execution time between JS with C or C#?

Comment: There is no point. I'm playing with technologies.

Comment: If it takes 2m35s to do this with buffer size of 100,000, why does it surprise you that it seems to be hanging when you multiply that buffer by 10? You realise that's an exponential change right? I couldn't even begin to guess how long it would take, but I'd be surprised if it didn't take hours at that stage.

Comment: @Thor84no, yeah I realize, but I hope to get the answer somehow but Chrome just hangs. That is disappointing.

Comment: @Artjom It hangs because you're using all of the time it has to redraw to processing... nothing. It's most likely just still doing it, you just haven't left it until it crashed/completed the calculation yet.

Comment: This is bubble sort, not selection sort...

Comment: Hey @Artjom! You can make it faster by doing `i < bufferSize - 1` (note the -1). The last check is unnecessary.

Comment: @Pluto no it's selection sort. Bubble sort always swaps indexes that are right beside each other. Both are O(n^2), but selection sort does way less swaps.

Comment: @dhsto Ahh, I see where my confusion came from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Chrome has the tendency of hanging during long operations, and sometimes will crash. I've done things in Chrome and Firefox, and Chrome would just crash the tab as for Firefox it would take forever as well, but it wouldn't crash. I would keep getting the Continue/Stop Script popup though on Firefox.

If you're saying it's taking around 20 minutes to complete in `c` then I would imagine that the web browser would take long (if not longer), and in most cases browsers will attempt to kill the script.